# I tried to install python package.Then some error is showing like "exeption....." why?

Tags: permissions, python

Friends,I downloaded and installed pip in my Ubuntu.Then I tried to install packages like PLY and My xml etc.But i got a a sequence of sentences written in red.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 731, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 841, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1040, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 343, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 314, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 82, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ply'
```

I used `pip install ply` to install.

What can i do for install packages?

Comment: you at least forgot to include "sudo"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip` creates a directory for each package under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` (replace `2.7` for other versions) to keep all the necessary files, so you need to have sufficient permission to create that directory.

In your case, you do not have sufficient permission to create `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ply` directory thats why `pip` is failing.

To solve this, you can use `sudo`:

```
sudo pip install ply
```

Or better you can add yourself to the `staff` group as the relevant directories created by `pip` under `/usr/local/lib/` is owned by user `root` and group `staff` (with `setgid`).

So you can do:

```
sudo usermod -a -G staff username
```

Now logout and log back in, now the following should work:

```
pip install ply
```

Answer (score 1):

The only obvious error I see is

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

That means you forgot to start the command with `sudo`. Change the command to ...

```
sudo pip install ply
```